# Is it possible to merge/merge multiple structs into one dynamically (using reflect)?

Tags: json, reflection, go

I need to build a function which merges responses from multiple other functions into one (struct). Currently I'm thinking that the only way would be to create a map[string]interface{} and then range over the fields of structs I need to merge and assign field name -> value as key, values in the map. Is there any other way? I basically just need to embed two structs into one.

Comment: I am unsure if I understand the problem. Maybe you should show code of what you would like to merge into what.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but you can definitely embed structs into one struct and access the properties directly. You wouldn't need to use reflection and might I add that its often the case that reflection is frowned upon since its more preferable to be explicit; reflection is often implicit.

Here is some code, that hopefully addresses what you wanted:

```
type Foo struct {
  Bar
  Baz
}

type Bar struct {
  BarValue string
}

type Baz struct {
  BazValue string
}

func main() {
  test := Foo{Bar: Bar{BarValue: "bar"}, Baz: Baz{BazValue: "baz"}}
  fmt.Println(test.BarValue)
  fmt.Println(test.BazValue)
}
```